# Grep redirection is pulling more information that I want in log.txt

Tags: grep, centos, selinux

I want the output of the sed file edit to go into my log file name d_selinuxlog.txt. Currently, grep outputs the specified string as well as 3 other strings above and below in the edited file.

```
#!/bin/bash

{ getenforce;

sed -i s/SELINUX=enforcing/SELINUX=disabled /etc/selinux/config; 

grep "SELINUX=*" /etc/selinux/config > /home/neb/scropts/logs/d_selinuxlog.txt; 

setenforce 0;
getenforce; }
```

I want to be seeing just `SELINUX=disabled` in the log file

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for sharing the code you've tried so far. Please include a sample of actual input and your exact desired output.

Comment: "SELINUX=*" means `SELINUX` followed by zero or more `=`'s. Try `"SELINUX=.*"` so the `=` can limit your input.

Answer (score 1):

All the lines with the lines SELINUX are going to match, even the commented ones, so, you need to omit that ones, and the * from the match.

```
grep "SELINUX=" /etc/selinux/config | grep -v "#"
```

This is my output

```
17:52:07 alvaro@lykan /home/alvaro 
$ grep "SELINUX=" /etc/selinux/config | grep -v "#"
SELINUX=disabled
17:52:22 alvaro@lykan /home/alvaro
```